# Outlook app doesn't sync email when data roaming (WiFi turned off)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, outlook, cellular-data

**Phone:** Lumia 650 Dual Sim

**OS:** Windows 10

**App:** Outlook Mail, Outlook Calendar

Everytime I roam, outside of my home network, with data enabled and WiFi disabled, I run in to this error:

[image]

It is worth noting, only the Outlook apps (Mail, Calendar) stop working. All other apps work with data as per usual.

I have read somewhere that this is because background data is restricted for the app (while roaming) but I don't know how to control this.